# Laravel's project deployment on shared hosting throws error 500

Tags: shared-hosting

I want to deploy a laravel’s project on a shared hosting (ovh)

I have ftp access, and the folder’s architecture of the shared hostings is like this:

[image: clean hosting folder]

I have uploaded the laravel’s files to the root folder, and the content of public folder to `www`:

[image: uploaded project]

Also this is my `www/.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And this is my `.env` file:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:kUQEHrtug5E+ZOI99vKg+BKkfU6rdzH9pUXhmbDYzsg=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack



DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=XXXXXXX.XXXXX.XXXX
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=XXXXXXX
DB_USERNAME=XXXXXX
DB_PASSWORD=XXXXXXX

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=ssl0.ovh.net
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=XXXX@XXXXX.XXX
MAIL_PASSWORD=XXXXXXXX
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Once all of this is uploaded, I got the following error:

`This page isn't working. XXXXX is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP_ERROR 500`

I have set the permisions to `storage/logs` folder to 775

Anyone have a clue of what's going on?